# Как исправить соответствие цвета кнопок и бэкграундовой картинки в pyqt designer?

Tags: python, pyqt5

В pyqt designer задал в stylesheet формы заднефоновую картинку. Теперь картинка во всех кнопках (хотя у них должен быть свой цвет - тут он только как линия по краям кнопки). Видел, что нужно ставить не на форму, а на окно. А как это сделать в дизайнере? В инспекторе там сразу от формы идёт разветвление к кнопкам.

Comment: Можно фрейм растянуть под окно, благо оно у меня по размерам ещё не изменяется.
Ещё: кто-нибудь знает, как убрать эту верхнюю панель с кнопкой закрытия, чтобы сделать свою, как в лаунчерах игр?

Comment: Добавить в описание класса self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint) В моём случае при переводе из ui в py нужно было вставить в метод сетапуи класса уиформ Form.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint)